# Can I move the location of the well equipment?

Tags: well

Our well is located under the giant metal sheet that is in the picture below. I don't like that it is in our driveway. Is there any way that I can move the "plumbing" over like 10 feet? I don't really know what is under the cover to be honest either (as far as equipment goes). I think there is a pump under it? Couldn't I just move the pump over and reconnect the pipes? Or is that not how the well can be set up.

NOTE: The well is about 280' deep. The pressure tank is inside.

[image: Well cover]
[image: Under the cover]

Comment: If you don't know what's under that metal cover, it's not likely that anyone here does. Open the cover and take a photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely there is a pressure tank in the hole also. Depending on the well depth their could also be a surface pump (shallow well) and there should be a local disconnect. It is possible to move everything But because there is a slab the cost is going to be higher. If you just don't like the cover you will still need the well head to be accessible but from the photo it could be ~1/3 the size. It would be a good idea to know what is in the hole.

Comment: The pressure tank is inside the house. The well is at about 280' so I'm not sure if there is a surface pump? Would I be able to see the pump if it's a surface well or would it be slightly hidden or under the ground a bit?

Comment: A well that deep probably has a submersible pump. With the tank inside you could make the hole much smaller. Just make sure there is enough room for the day the pump gives out (not common) to open the well and pull the pipe and pump up.